# Can't post result alone surrogates because of jQuery raising "malformed URI" bug (Firefox only)

Tags: support, comments, firefox

I wanted to post result of JavaScript expression `JSON.stringify(String.fromCodePoint(128514).split(''))`

It's impossible - when posted as comment it cause page to reload, and when posted in question/answer jQuery throws `Malformed URI` error and cause endless spinning of "posting answer" (nothing is even sent to server).

Comment: `"["�","�"]"` - "["�","�"]"

Comment: Still no repro... could this be something in your network blocking that content?

Comment: I can reproduce it every time - Firefox 43 on Win 10.

Comment: And if you use another browser to test this?

Comment: For some reason, it looks like FF is trying to do a get request - with the comment details appended as a parameter to the query string.

Comment: Seems to work on other browsers. So it's FF specific bug.

Comment: you should totally drop that and try jQuery its really great and does all thigns.

Answer (score 8):

> It's impossible

It actually is! Splitting up a UTF-16 surrogate sequence gives you two strings each with a single surrogate in. JavaScript can cope with this because its strings are internally no more than sequences of UTF-16 code units, but they're not valid in terms of Unicode code point strings and they cannot be represented in UTF-8.

Like most web apps StackOverflow's input/output is all in UTF-8, so there isn't actually any way to get the data into the system.

I suspect the thing with Getting the long URL is because trying to encode the data into UTF-8 causes a JavaScript error, which stops the form submit handler from preventDefaulting the form, so the form submits as a native HTTP GET form.

Ideally SO perhaps could detect the bad string and complain earlier, and probably the add-comment form should be POST and its submit button should be `type="button"` so it doesn't accidentally work when JS is unavailable/broken.